# fopen() in PHP not resolving redirections with long location urls

Tags: php, header, http-headers, fopen

I'm trying to open file with `fopen()` from a link that has one or more (301/302) redirects before final file with response code 200 is reached. However when redirection has Location header with really long url, `fopen()` fails to resolve it and location header is also missing in the context.

Let me illustrate that...

We have 2 redirection files:

**...://test.com/redirectionWithShortLocation**

```
<?php
    header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg?test=abc");
```

**...://test.com/redirectionWithLongLocation**

```
<?php
    header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg?test=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");
```

And the third final PHP file that tries to open file from the link:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://test.com/redirectionWithShortLocation';
    //$url = 'http://test.com/redirectionWithLongLocation';

    $context = stream_context_create([
        'http' => [
            'ignore_errors' => true,
            'timeout'       => 3000,
            'follow_location' => 1,
            'max_redirects' => 20,
        ]
    ]);

    $fp       = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
    $meta     = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
    $respData = stream_get_contents($fp);
    fclose($fp);

    $responseLines = $meta['wrapper_data'];

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($responseLines);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit();
```

So when I am opening with above code the first url I get all the headers and also the response data is correct. However when I try to open second URL with really long location header, header is missing ing `$meta['wrapper_data']` and I don't get correct response data.

I know that I can overcome this by opening file with `curl`, however I would like to stay with fopen if possible.

Have anybody any idea how to overcome this issue/limitation while still using `fopen`?